# What's the best way of modeling 3d target motion with only 2d angle observations?

Tags: estimation, kalman-filters, filtering, sensor, tracking

A maneuvering target is flying in 3d cartesian space, but a sensor (passive infrared or mic array, etc.) can only observe it in polar coordinate with 2d orientations
(azimuth, elevation). For simplicity, there is only one target and one stationary observer fixed in origin coordinates. The question is what's the best way of modeling its states and motions for Kalman tracking?
[image]

From my investigations so far, there could be three approaches:

1. All in 3d format. represent location of target states and observations all onto a unit sphere ($X= [x, y, z], |X|=1$), and normalize the location each time after state correcting/predicting (as was done in a [sound source tracking system](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0921889017309399)).
2. All in 2d format (azimuth, elevation). Simplest but may not well simulate the linear motions in real 3d cartesian space, but with circular curves instead.
3. remain 3d location states and 2d angle observations, use EKF/UKF to tackle nonlinear transformation with constraint that $|X|=1$.

Comment: Have you researched "angle only tracking".  I've see a number of papers that transform these observations into 3 dimensions.  For example: [Range estimation using angle-only target tracking with particle filters](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/946218)

Comment: "people often use EKF/UKF ... since it's an invertible transformation"  Eh?  Do you mean you want to use $\mathbf x = \begin{bmatrix}x & y & z\end{bmatrix}^T,\ \| \mathbf x \| = 1$?  You certainly _can_ use this; I've done something similar with 3D orientations and unit quaternions.

Comment: This is a great problem statement, but for Stackexchange it's flawed, in the sense that Stackexchange wants one clear question that has one clear answer.  This question is the thesis statement for a wide-ranging discussion that may include opinions.  What it lacks is, first -- questions, i.e., some clear interrogative statement followed by a question mark, and second, questions that are complete and aren't subject to opinion (i.e., "what is best, A or B?" is an opinion question, but "what are the possible advantages of A vs. B?" leaves the opinion-making to the reader).

Comment: While you're pondering, you may want to break out your last scenario ("A further question") and ask it _as a separate question_.  Be sure to detail how there's both 2D and 3D sensors involved (presumably LiDaR and a conventional camera, at different frame rates, but **I don't know that**).  If you feel confident enough, propose a filter or parts of it, but expect people to modify what you've proposed.

Comment: @GrapefruitIsAwesome I believe it's related to this topic, but in a simpler form. Most of the "angle only tracking" papers I read so far are trying to reconstruct the 3d space trajectory by moving the observers or other complex techniques, which is beyond my expectation. I've simplified my question yet.

Comment: The "best" way to do something depends on your objective, and possibly your application. My intuition would say that 2D-focused approaches would probably be sufficient (maybe not best) for modeling objects in a steady state velocity or acceleration (e.g., airliner). 3D-focused approaches would probably be necessary for more chaotic objects such as a butterfly.

Comment: Interesting question. I believe it can be attempted using a Kalman filter, but the missing part for me is what Ash alludes to:  What is your model of motion?  How do you expect the target to move?  For example, [this Mathworks page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/state-estimation-with-wrapped-measurements-using-extended-kalman-filter-control.html) decides that the states are $x$,$y$, and $z$ and the associated time derivatives and they all are just random walks.  If you know more about how the target moves, encoding more of that into the model will allow the estimate to be better.

Comment: ... and conversely to what @PeterK. said, if if you encode "all that" into a model _and get it wrong_ then it'll make things worse.

Comment: @TimWescott. All models are wrong. Some are useful. :-) I did say **If you know more about how the target moves**. Clearly, if you don't it'll go poorly.

Answer (score 1):

So, let's see how to start this.  Let's make the states the 3D location and the 3D velocities:
$$
\mathbf{x}_k = \left [ 
x_k\ \dot{x}_k\ y_k\ \dot{y}_k\ z_k\ \dot{z}_k
\right ]^T
$$
Then, following the [Mathworks page I referenced in my comment](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/state-estimation-with-wrapped-measurements-using-extended-kalman-filter-control.html), let's just assume a random walk for the state update equation:
$$
\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{x}_{k} + \epsilon_k
$$
where
$$\mathbf{A} = \left [\begin{array}{cccccc}
1 & \Delta t & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0  \\
0 & 0 &1 & \Delta t & 0 & 0   \\
0 & 0 &0 & 1 & 0 & 0   \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & \Delta t  \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1   \\
\end{array} \right]
$$
and $\epsilon_k$ is the independent, identically distributed process noise.

Then the output equation is just
$$
\mathbf{z}_k = \left [ 
\begin{array}{c}
\arcsin\left(\frac{z_k}{ \sqrt{x_k^2 + y_k^2 + z_k^2}}\right)\\
\arctan\left(\frac{y_k}{ x_k}\right)\\ 
\end{array}
 \right ] + \eta_k
$$
where $\eta_k$ is the measurement noise and the measurements are the elevation
$$\phi = \arcsin\left(\frac{z_k}{ \sqrt{x_k^2 + y_k^2 + z_k^2}}\right)$$
and the azimuth
$$\psi = \arctan \left(\frac{y_k}{ x_k}\right)$$

And I'd just then apply your EKF equations to that.  I can't see a good reason to normalize $|\mathbf{x}_k | = 1$, just with what I've written.

It may be that the model doesn't work well without some sort of correction, but I'd try it without the normalization first.